# Square buttons using bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular7, angular8

I am new to bootstrap and angular:

I want to make three parallel square buttons using bootstrap. Page should be something like this::

..............................................................................................................................................................

```
                                   My title(in center)


Square button-1                     square button-2               Square button-3
```

My code is as follows::

```
<div class="col-md-12 pt-md-5 text-center">My Title<div>
  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <div>
        <button>button-1</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>button-2</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>button-3</button>
    </div>    
  </div>
```

What should I do to make buttons square using bootstrap and change color and height of text as required?

```
.button-wrapper{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

I don't want to use css rather I would like to use bootstrap for having sqaure button and want to write a long text in square button instead of button-1, button-2 and button-3

Answer (score 3):

To make the actual buttons exactly square will be close to impossible since that will depend on screen size and content. You could make them all the same size and width using Bootstrap's grid layout. Something like this:

```
<div class="col-4 text-center d-flex">
    <button class="btn btn-primary p-4 rounded-0">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </button>
</div>
```

The above code wraps a single button in a div (.col-4) that is a third of the grid. The .col-4 display property is flex so its content will automatically fit its height. Copy this layout for the other two buttons and you've got three equal height buttons that will always be the same height even if the content length differs.

See a working example at https://codepen.io/BluSilva/pen/xxVReVg

**Side note:** If you're trying to make the corners square, bootstrap has a class that controls border-radius so to make a button with square corners, you could simply add the **"rounded-0"** class to the button's classes.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary rounded-0">My Button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `border-radious: 0 !important;`
(not 'none' as the other answers here state)

```css
.btn{
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">buton-1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">buton-1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">buton-1</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The bootstrap supported method is to use the SCSS/SASS source files set the SCSS variable to $enable-rounded to false. If you have included bootstrap into your project with NPM you can use something like:

```
$enable-rounded: false;

@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

There are a number of SCSS variables that can be overridden: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#variable-defaults